# Active X control custom events fail to fire in Javascript

Tags: javascript, c++, com, activex

I have written a custom active X control using the IDispatch interface that I would like to communicate with javascript. I have successfully gotten the javascript -> COM path working; I can call a javascript function on my active x object and receive a corresponding INVOKE call in my dll.

To receive events on the javascript side, I am following the advice in this article: http://jeffcode.blogspot.com/2008/02/how-to-create-activex-control-that.html

When I load my test page, I get a call to FindConnectionPoint followed by a call to Advise, as I would expect. When I call Invoke on the interface given by Advise, I get a success status message, but nothing happens on the js side!

This is the javascript code I am using to test event handling:

```
function FooActiveX::ReceiveMessage(msg)
{
    alert(msg);
}
```

Interestingly, if I remove that, I don't get the calls to FindConnectionPoint or Advise anymore, so it's doing SOMETHING.

Any advice on how to debug this problem or things to try would be very helpful. Thank you!

My idl interface definition file looks like this:

```
[
uuid("1bf6bb1a-3232-11e4-a195-a6c5e4d22fb7"),
version(1.0),
]
library FooControlLib
{
interface IFooControl;
dispinterface DFooControlEvents;

importlib("stdole2.tlb");

[
    uuid("1bf6bb1a-3232-11e4-a195-a6c5e4d22fb8"),
    hidden
]
dispinterface DFooControlEvents
{
    properties:
    methods:
        [id(DISPID_RECEIVEMESSAGE)]  void ReceiveMessage( [in] BSTR msg );
}

[
    odl,
    dual,
    uuid("1bf6bb1a-3232-11e4-a195-a6c5e4d22fb9"),
    oleautomation
]
interface IFooControl : IDispatch
{
    [id(DISPID_SENDMESSAGE)] HRESULT SendMessage( [in] BSTR msg);
}

[
    uuid("1bf6bb1a-3232-11e4-a195-a6c5e4d22fc0")
]
coclass FooControl
{
    [default] interface IFooControl;
    [source, default] dispinterface DFooControlEvents;
}
}
```

EDIT: It seems that the problem is related to the parameter in the ReceiveMessage method. If I remove the "msg" parameter, the alert box will display properly.

Answer (score 0):

Found my problem. The arguments to the method are passed to Invoke as an array of VARIANTARG structures. I had set the value, but not the vt member of that struct, which identifies the type of the parameter. I don't know why invoke returned an OK status.